Controlling position of MUI Datepicker v6 popover in absence of textField
I'm rendering a Datepicker without a text field and it's getting positioned in the upper left hand corner of the screen no matter what slotProps popper properties I pass in to position it. From other posts, I understand that the problem is that it anchors the popover on the text field and in the absence of a text field, it positions it in the upper left of the screen.
From other posts, I gather than I might solve this with a custom TextField, but I'm not sure what form that should take or if there is a simpler or more idiomatic solution. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's code and a sandbox which demonstrates the problem:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DemoContainer } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/demo";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <DemoContainer components={["DatePicker"]}>
          <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            Toggle Calendar Open/Closed
          </button>
          <DatePicker
            open={open}
            onClose={() => {
              setOpen(false);
            }}
            slots={{ textField: () => null }}
          />
        </DemoContainer>
      </div>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

As a related aside, the AI bots that I've asked about this seem only to be knowledgeable about v5.

Could you please put all of your code so that we can reproduce what you are trying to do? Also maybe having a codesandbox linked could be pretty nice :). Something like this

You may use StaticDatePicker if you don't want the TextField and control it's visibility as <StaticDatePicker sx={{display:open?"block":"none"}}/>

Appreciate the quick feedback, @RaphaelCanciani, and the nudge to use codesandbox. See the updated post for a simple example.

@discovrer Thanks for the suggestion. I still want the popover behavior, but if there's a not a reasonable way to set the anchor for the dynamic datepicker, I guess I can introduce my own Popover component.

Why dont you just use the mui <DateCalendar/> component? Here

The app is intended to run well on a phone and I only want the calendar to appear when a calendar icon is pressed. The example I gave above was just the simplest version I could concoct to demonstrate the problem.

I added .MuiPaper-root.MuiPickersPopper-paper {   position: absolute !important;   left: 100px !important; } to root css and it changes position. Forked Implementation. Does this help?

Well, it's helpful in that it demonstrates a mechanism to adjust the position of the popover, but it still leaves the problem of how to position it relative to the button that opens the calendar.

@RaphaelCanciani The codesandbox you provided (and hence my derivative instance of it) seems not to have survived the latest library updates. Any chance you could you provide an updated version or point me in the direction of where to find one?

@RaphaelCanciani DateCalendar does not provide the popover capability that DatePicker does.

For v7, you can specify the position of the DatePicker calendar by using the slotProps property as follows:
                slotProps={{
                    popper: {
                        anchorEl: document.getElementById('event-icon'),
                    },
                }}

Sorry, but I can't recall where I found this detail. You can, of course, use whatever you want for the anchorEl value.

We faced the same bug after updating MUI date picker from 6 to 7. The generic solution was:
const periodRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

<DateRangePicker
  slotProps={{
    popper: {
      anchorEl: periodRef.current,
    },

